# Separate form submissions by campaign in analytics

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

I have two campaigns running in Google Analytics at the same time, and, in my website, I have a contact form.

Is there any way that I can see from which of the campaigns came the message that was sent to me?

For example, John has clicked in the campaign-one and send me a message, and Mario has clicked in the campaign-two and send me a message. I want to know that John came from the campaign-one and Mario from the campaign-two.

I have already been mapping events in my site, but I can't figure it out how to separate if the form came from campaign-one or campaign-two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've set your `campaign-one` and `campaign-two` values to the `utm_campaign` parameter in your campaign tagging, it will show up in the Campaign dimension in Google Analytics.

I'm assuming by "I have already been mapping events", you mean that you have implemented [event tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events) on your site for these form submissions.

You can either build a custom report in Google Analytics that includes the Campaign dimension *and* the event dimensions (Event Category, Event Action, Event Label), or you can add Campaign as a secondary dimension to an events report. For example, in the **Behavior > Events > Top Events** report, choose "Secondary Dimension" and then select the "Campaign" dimension. That would break up the event numbers by which campaign the session was acquired from.

[image: Add campaign as a secondary dimension]

Similarly, you can look at the **Acquisition > Campaigns > All Campaigns** report and add one of the event dimensions as a secondary dimension there, to see campaigns broken down by events that they resulted in.